# error NETSDK1152: Found multiple publish output files with the same relative in Azure DevOps Publish Task

Tags: azure-devops

error NETSDK1152: Found multiple publish output files with the same relative in Azure DevOps Publish Task

I am getting this error while running the aspdotnet.

error **NETSDK1152**: Found multiple publish output files with the same relative path: D:\a\1\s\src\PartsUnlimited.Models\config.json, D:\a\1\s\src\PartsUnlimitedWebsite\config.json. [D:\a\1\s\src\PartsUnlimitedWebsite\PartsUnlimitedWebsite.csproj]

Anyone has solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

Please nevermind, I got it reseolved..There were duplicate files. Thanks,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).